# What is the difference between a `slot variable` and a `non-slot variable` in the Tensorflow internal optimizer API?

Tags: python, optimization, tensorflow

I'm familiar with the Tensorflow Optimizer API and have used the slot variables via the `_create_slots()` method in `optimizer.Optimizer`, though I'm no expert, I've hacked my way into understanding this API.

In the 1.6RC1 release notes (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases) there is the following point about slot variables which I don't understand fully:

> New Optimizer internal API for non-slot variables. Descendants of
>   AdamOptimizer that access _beta[12]_power will need to be updated.

What are the non-slot variables being referenced here?

What is the difference between slot and non-slot variables in the API?

Comment: It's referring to [slots](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/__slots__magic.html#slots-magic). There is some API that evidently optimizes slots differently than non-slots. Further, if you subclass that optimizer and access that named interface, your code will be broken, according to the notes. Not sure if that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Slot variables in a TensorFlow optimizer are sub-variables associated with each trainable variable. For instance, if you have a variable `Variable1`, you could add a slot named `MovingAverage`, which would have the name `Variable1/MovingAverage`.

Non-slot variables are variables that are part of the optimizer and not associated with any trainable variable, for example the counter in Adam in LucasB's answer in the question linked by David Parks.

See the [`tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer#slots_2)
for an explanation of slots in the docs. Also note that afaik Keras (TF2) optimizers do not explicitly support non-slot variables - it looks like `optimizer._set_hyper()` is the way to do that in TF2.

Also - systech's comment is incorrect - slots and non-slot variables have nothing to do with Python's `__slots__` functionality.

Comment: So should people store global scalars used by their custom optimizers as hyperparameters, even though they are not intended to be set from outside?